# Number of asymmetric partial functions over a finite non-empty set

Tags: combinatorics, functions, relations

Let $S$ be a finite non-empty set.

I recently used the presumed fact that the number of asymmetric partial functions over $S$ is $3^{|S|-1}(|S|-1)!$, after I became quite convinced of it, since it worked for $|S|\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and would be rather unusual not to continue like that. Unfortunately, I could not come up with a proof since.

I unsuccessfully tried it by induction, and to derive it from the number $3^{\frac{|S|^2-|S|}{2}}$ of asymmetric relations, and the number $(|S|+1)^{|S|}$ of partial functions, over $S$, which are both easy to show. Also, I failed to find an existing proof on the internet.

Does anyone know or see how this could be done, and might have some hint?

Comment: I also noticed that it coincides with the number of antisymmetric functions over $S$, which did not help.

Clearly, if my conjecture is true, for a possible inductive proof one would have to show that when a distinct element is added to $S$, the number is multiplied by $3|S|$.

Comment: What is an "asymmetric partial function", please?

Comment: An asymmetric (that is, antisymmetric and irreflexive) relation which is a partial function.

Comment: So, if $f(a)=b$, then $f(b)$ is not $a$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: If you include the empty function then my count for $n=4$ is $163$ whereas your formula gives $162$.

Comment: I see, and how did you come up with $163$?

Comment: Brute force exhaustive count.

Comment: You seem to be right, I just write a program to count it. With pen and paper, the cases just seemed too similar. I will check my program once more for correctness, but since we got the same result, it will probably be fine. But maybe this gives rise to another (correct) formula. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEIS sequence [A089466](http://oeis.org/A089466) seems to be what you're looking for. The first few values, starting with $n=0$, are
$$1,1,3,18,163,1950,28821$$
It says here that

> $a(n)$ is the number of functions $f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that the functional digraph contains no cycles of length $2$ — Geoffrey Critzer

which are the same as your "asymmetric partial functions" if you delete the cycles of length $1$.

Comment: Yes, or just "antisymmetric functions", as I wrote in another comment. But that's it, exactly, thanks!

Comment: Just to make that clear, since there seemed to have been some more confusion about this before, **anti**symmetry allows cycles of length $1$, but none of length $2$, whereas **a**symmetry allows neither of them. Thus, there is an obvious bijection between the set of **a**symmetric **partial** functions over $S$ and the set of **anti**symmetric functions over $S$. In any case, that sequence perfectly captures it.